# Playing video from within app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I am trying to play a local video from my app using AVPlayer. I have looked everywhere but can't find any useful tutorials/demos/documentation. Here is what I am trying, but it is not playing. Any idea why? The URL is valid because I was using the same one to play a video using MPMoviePlayer successfully.

```
       Video *currentVideo = [videoArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filepath = currentVideo.videoURL;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: fileURL];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];
    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];


    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;


    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];


    [self.player play];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're assuming that after executing this line `AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: fileURL];` the asset is ready to use. This is not the case as noted in the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW2):

```
    You create an asset from a URL using AVURLAsset. Creating the asset, however, 
    does not necessarily mean that it’s ready for use. To be used, an asset must 
    have loaded its tracks.
```

After creating the asset try loading it's tracks:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[tracksKey] completionHandler:
 ^{
     NSError *error;
     AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];

     if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) { 

         // At this point you know the asset is ready
         self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

         ...
     }
 }];
```

Please refer to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW2) to see the complete example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @LuisCien i am facing the same problem now, and i have used your code. but it returned me `AVKeyValueStatusFailed`, please see my question and suggest me some if you understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255776/cannot-get-the-duration-of-mp4-file-by-using-avasset-or-avurlasset