# iOS- how to get the duration of .mp4 file by using AVAsset or AVURLAsset

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mp4, duration, avasset

i know duration of video type questions have been answered before but i am facing real trouble in getting duration of an `.mp4` file by using `AVAsset` and by `AVURLAsset`. i am using Following code

```
NSString *itemPathString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:obmodel.actualname];
NSURL *itemPathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:itemPathString];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:itemPathString]){

    NSLog(@"File Exists");
}

AVAsset *videoAsset = (AVAsset *)[AVAsset assetWithURL:itemPathURL];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration));
if(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration) >= 59.0){
}
```

but every time it returns `0`
i have also imported following `headers`

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

i have also tried some other code that i know but neither one worked for me.
My video is working properly if I play it through `iExplorer`, my Path is good but don't know whats i'm missing.
i would like to share that what i have found is that my `AVAssets` are not loaded properly
please suggest me what should be done.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19327187/1702077) may help.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam thanks for the reply. i used his method and it returned me `AVKeyValueStatusFailed`
what would be the error in my case?

Comment: what should be the tracksKey?

Comment: Hi @SyedAliSalman, need your help in stackoverflow.com/questions/55605987/… ... This Question is same like this .. please take a look at this... Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I've had similar problems before. For me the problem went away when I used:

```
NSURL *itemPathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:itemPathString];
```

instead of

```
NSURL *itemPathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:itemPathString];
```

If you're completely sure your path is ok, this should fix your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @LuisCien, need your help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605987/issue-while-merging-video-audio-ios-swift4 ... This Question is same like this .. please take a look at this... Thanks