# Issue while merging Video & Audio iOS swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swift4, avmutablecomposition

```
2019-04-10 10:49:51.590008+0500 VTKaraokeView[869:1039603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

Hi iOS Gurus! I'm merging Video & Audio files(.mp4 & .mp3 file)...

**BACKGROUND & PROBLEM STATEMENT:-**

As I'm working on an App like karaoke... I'm recording Video with Background Music and then AFTER MERGING this recorded video & background music into new **newVideo.mp4** file and then Playing **.newVideo.mp4** into **AVPlayerViewController**... As this works perfect BUT the problem is when my recorded video exceeds from almost 10 seconds then I'm getting this above exception. AND this exception occurs on this Line **let aAudioOfVideoTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]**

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl: URL, audioUrl:URL)
{
    let savePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")

    do { // delete old video
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl as URL)
    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }


    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    //start merge
    let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let aAudioOfVideoTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] // HERE i'm getting Error...Index Array Out Of Bound... 
    let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

    do{
        try mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioOfVideoTrack , at: kCMTimeZero)
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
        //instead of audioAsset duration

        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //Use this instead above line if your audiofile and video file's playing durations are same

        //            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    }catch{

    }

    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

    let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)//CGSize(1280,720)




    finalPath = savePathUrl.absoluteString

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl as URL
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
            print("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: check your array count before accessing it

Comment: If recorded Video is almostt less then 10 seconds then ARRAY COUNT is 1 & if it exceeds from 10/12 seconds then ARRAY COUNT is 0... so that why this goes to crash...

Comment: I am not sure about recorded times, but it is happening because of array empty, You need to search about recording issue

Comment: Yes i know its Happening due to ARRAY... but dont know the REASON...

Answer (score 3):

Spent almost 1 day to solve this & This is the perfect solution for this...

After a lot got help from [iOS 8 iPad AVCaptureMovieFileOutput drops / loses / never gets audio track after 13 - 14 seconds of recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735627/ios-8-ipad-avcapturemoviefileoutput-drops-loses-never-gets-audio-track-after) ...

Just add this line & works like a charm

```
avCaptureMovieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
```